# Why does this preg_replace skip the first instance of replacement text?

Tags: php, preg-replace

In the replacement script below, If the $myKeyword is "test" and the replacement text is "This, test can be a test", I would expect the replaced text to be "This, <b>test can be a <em>test</em>"

However, what I'm getting is: This, test can be a <b>test</b>.

I'm trying to determine why its skipping over the first instance of the keyword "test".

```
function save_rseo_content($content){
    global $post;
    $mykeyword = rseo_getKeyword($post);
    $mykeyword = " ".preg_quote($mykeyword, '/');

     /*had to add " " before keyword so that the it skips the instance
       where the keyword has already been formatted. Only matches " keyword"*/

    $theContent = 
    preg_replace_callback("/\b($mykeyword)\b/i","doReplace", $content);
return $theContent;
}

function doReplace($matches)
{
    static $count = 0;
    switch($count++) {
    case 0: return ' <b>'.trim($matches[1]).'</b>';
    case 1: return ' <em>'.trim($matches[1]).'</em>';
    case 2: return ' <u>'.trim($matches[1]).'</u>';
    default: return $matches[1];
        }
}
```

Comment: @Scott: It works fine for me..please check again.

Comment: There's probably something you're not telling us... ;) Because it works fine here.

Comment: Must be something with the wordpress pre-parser then. I'll look further upstream. I think its an issue with how WP is replacing the comma. If I remove the comma, it works fine.

Comment: In that case, the question is incorrect.

Comment: I found the missing bit of information and I've updated the question. The problem appears to be the empty space I'm adding before the keyword. This is required to keep the filter from replacing on keywords that are already formatted with the replacement text.

Comment: In other words. If you run this against a document multiple times (as when editing content and publishing), the replacement occurs each time building on itself unless you add the space before the keyword. I probably need to add a regex to check for the ">" character instead of the empty space hack.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than detecting a space before the keyword, it would probably be better to use a negative lookbehind for a > character:

```
preg_replace_callback("/\b(?<!>)($mykeyword)\b/i","doReplace", $content);
```